# Mysql Display rows in a Single Query

Tags: mysql

I have a Table containing 4 columns. I want print col1,col2,col3 like this

```
Col1   Col2   Col3  Col4
X       Y      Z     1
X       Y      
X              Z
        Y      Z
               Z
```

Can it be possible in a single query??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your recent edit, it appears that you just want to select all four columns, but order the result set ascending by `Col4`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Col4
```